# Recurrence relation with two variables

Tags: linear-algebra, generating-functions, recurrences, functional-equations

I am stuck on a recurrence relation with two variables. I'm familiar with techniques to solve recurrence relations with one variable and looked into ways to solve recurrence relations with multiple variables, but I somehow always end up with a huge mess. This is the recurrence relation:

\begin{align}
[2N(1-\lambda) + 4\lambda]f(i,j) &= \lambda f(i-1,j) + \lambda f(i,j-1) + \lambda f(i+1, j) + \lambda f(i, j+1),  \quad i, j > 0 \text{ and } i+j \leq N-3
\end{align}
\begin{align}
[2N(1-\lambda) + 3\lambda]f(i,0) &= \lambda f(i-1,0) + \lambda f(i,1) + \lambda f(i+1,0), \quad 0 < i \leq N-3 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
[2N(1-\lambda) + 3\lambda]f(0,j) &= \lambda f(0,j-1) + \lambda f(1,j) + \lambda f(0,j+1), \quad 0 < j \leq N-3 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
[2N(1-\lambda) + 2\lambda]f(0,0) &= \lambda f(1, 0) + \lambda f(0,1) 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
f(i,j) = 1, \quad i+j = N-2.
\end{align}

Here, $N$ is some positive integer ($N \geq 5$) and $\lambda \in (0,1)$. I'm looking for an explicit expression for $f(i,j)$ in terms of $i$, $j$, $N$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: If you put $b_i=f(i,N-3-i)$  then you get  recurrence relations with one indices

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But how then do I deal with terms $f(i,j)$ where $j \neq N-3-i$?

Comment: I just corrected a mistake in the first equation by the way... It should hold for $i+j < N-3$ instead of $i+j = N-3$.

Comment: I want to find an explicit expression for $f(i,j)$ in terms of $i$, $j$, $\lambda$ and $N$. Should have specified that indeed...

Comment: This looks like the discrete Laplace equation on the square lattice, with a certain boundary condition, see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator .

Answer (score 3):

The following is an answer to the original version of the question.

Your system of equations can be rewritten as follows: For integers $i$ and $j$ in $[0,n-2]$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(2n r+4)f(i,j) =& f(i-1,j) + f(i,j-1) + f(i+1, j) + f(i, j+1) \\ 
&\text{if}\quad  0<i<i+j<n-3,
\end{aligned}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(2n r+3)f(i,0) &= f(i-1,0) + f(i,1) + f(i+1,0) \\ 
&\text{if}\quad  0<i<n-3, 
\end{aligned}
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(2n r+3)f(0,j) &= f(0,j-1) + f(1,j) + f(0,j+1) \\ 
&\text{if}\quad  0<j<n-3, 
\end{aligned}
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(2n r+2)f(0,0) &= f(1, 0) + f(0,1), 
\end{aligned}
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(i,n-2-i) = 1 \quad\text{if}\quad  0\le i\le n-2,
\end{aligned}
\tag{5}\label{5}
\end{equation}
where $n:=N$ and $r:=(1-\lambda)/\lambda\in(0,\infty)$.
Note that, if $n=5$, then condition \eqref{1} is vacuous.

Already for $n=6$, there are infinitely many solutions of the linear system \eqref{1}--\eqref{5}. These solutions are given by the following:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(0,4)&=1\\ 
f(1,0)&=(12 r+2) f(0,0)-f(0,1)\\ 
f(1,1)&=(12 r+3) f(0,1)-f(0,0)-f(0,2)\\ 
f(1,2)&=(12 r+3) f(0,2)-f(0,1)-f(0,3)\\ 
f(1,3)&=1\\ 
f(2,0)&=(12 r+3) f(1,0)-f(0,0)-f(1,1)\\ 
f(2,1)&=(12 r+4) f(1,1)-f(0,1)-f(1,0)-f(1,2)\\ 
f(2,2)&=1\\ 
f(3,0)&=(12 r+3)f(2,0)-f(1,0)-f(2,1)\\ 
f(3,1)&=1\\ 
f(4,0)&=1
\end{aligned}
\tag{6}\label{6}
\end{equation}
We see that, of the the $15$ variables $f(i,j)$ (for $n=6$), the four variables $f(0,0),f(0,1),f(0,2),f(0,3)$ are "free", in the sense that one can give $f(0,0),f(0,1),f(0,2),f(0,3)$ any values and then compute the corresponding values of the remaining $15-4=11$ variables according to \eqref{6}.

Comment: I get one solution for $n=6$ with $f(0,0)=\frac{48r+11}{62208r^5+77760r^4+34560r^3+6660r^2+525r+11}$. [Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtkd1qg0AQhe8F32HI1a4_IeaiF1IDPkChya1I0LraVbOGjYpt6bt3Rm2jocuCy5kzZz9nT9tnfYAAXpv6QzUXmdQnqQp2PHLTMA2FlSfTyDP8Rkw6UHLIGw0SpAKdqEIw5XqTVi41iWpsGmmFjV_QJ7UPMhtgas4GhyTyC9VdhE5awfKMwzfdGdJd0S4GC2qhRp26zmTPMwolw7KOgGioHJgJH3N90wBcMkduGzmDABS4sJ91WmFUxbgx2buL6UoR9U3827G3lKXvBWLp8AcJgzEcBDERm_13ckocz3SwPc4XqTNnB4cAdpCoDHPo-GBZAtgr5lU1rSJGKDwmTtej8d6aml71JWm1HFjItyj04qxl8d6yXry1jWYpn2e6fKpPecVhOkABv8hXLVXLRtfG34xW_gOvHJaN&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate response! The one thing that is missing in my system of equations I think is the fact that $f$ is symmetrical, that is $f(i,j) = f(j,i)$ for each $i,j$. So in case of $n = 6$, if we only consider $f(i,j)$ with $i \geq j$, then we are left with only 9 variables instead of 15 and then the system would have only one solution right? Do you think a closed form solution would exist in this case?

Comment: Also, the Markov chain/random walk interpretation is in fact where I got this system from! What I'm actually trying to find is the value of $\mathbb{E}[\lambda^{\tau_{i,j}]}$, where $\tau_{i,j}$ is the hitting time to this sloped boundary of the discrete triangle $T$ from a point $(i,j)$. But the chain is a little bit different from what you ar suggesting: from each point you can jump to a neighbouring point with probability $1/{2n}$ and you stay at the same point with the remaining probability (which is $1-4/{2n}$ in case of 4 neighbours and $1-3/{2n}$ in case of 3 neighbours etc.)

Comment: Ah, I've found the discrepancy. I misread the question as what @user675763 surely *intended*, which is to replace all of the $< N - 3$ with $\le N - 3$ so that every cell in the triangle has a constraint, rather than having an antidiagonal at $i + j = N - 3$ which is unconstrained.

Comment: Ah yes!! You are completely right! Thanks for pointing this out @PeterTaylor!

Comment: The above linked Sage code gives unique solution $f(0, 0) = 27/6887$, $f(0, 1) = f(1, 0) = 162/6887$, $f(1, 1) = 1007/6887$, $f(0, 2) = f(2, 0) = 1072/6887$, $f(0, 3) = f(1, 2) = f(2, 1) = f(3, 0) = 1$ for $n=5, r=1$. Where's the further discrepancy?

Comment: @PeterTaylor : Unfortunately, I cannot read Sage code. However, it appears that your output involves points $(a,b)$ with $a+b=4$, which should not be there for $n=5$. Anyhow, I have redone the [calculations](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZIc170ZUXVvKLcMg6LywPIMOeLXvJxWQhvV) (in Mathematica) and got yest another solution, in addition to the two solutions above. For $n=5$, the system consists just of $10$ equations (including the symmetry and boundary conditions) with $10$ unknowns (not accounting for the symmetry or boundary conditions).

Comment: Previous comment continued: So, I would suggest you too re-check your calculations.

Comment: You're looking at the output for $n = 6$. Change the third line (`n = 6`) for different values of $n$. If I'm reading `Out[11]` correctly in your output, you don't seem to be constraining `f[0, 2]` and `f[2, 0]` except to be equal to each other.

Comment: @PeterTaylor : You are right. I had replaced $<n-3$ by $\le n-3$ only in (1).

Comment: Thanks a lot to you both for your time! Do you think that it would be possible to find an explicit expression for $f(i,j)$ for general $n$? I have tried using generating functions, but no success so far...

Answer (score 1):

The solutions look like a mess, so it's not too surprising that you always end up with one. If we follow Iosif Pinelis in dividing all by the last constraint by $\lambda$ and substituting $r = \frac{1-\lambda}\lambda$ then

#### N=3 (trivial)

\begin{eqnarray*}f(0, 0) &=& \frac{1}{3r+1} \end{eqnarray*}

#### N=4

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(0, 0) &=& \frac{1}{(8r+1)(2r+1)} \\
f(0, 1) = f(1, 0) &=& \frac{4r + 1}{(8r+1)(2r+1)} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

#### N=5

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(0, 0) &=& \frac{20r + 7}{(50r^2 + 20r + 1)(50r^2 + 40r + 7)} \\
f(0, 1) = f(1,0) &=& \frac{(5r + 1)(20r + 7)}{(50r^2 + 20r + 1)(50r^2 + 40r + 7)} \\
f(0, 2) = f(2, 0) &=& \frac{500r^3 + 450r^2 + 115r + 7}{(50r^2 + 20r + 1)(50r^2 + 40r + 7)}  \\
f(1, 1) &=& \frac{500r^3 + 400r^2 + 100r + 7}{(50r^2 + 20r + 1)(50r^2 + 40r + 7)}  \\
\end{eqnarray*}

#### N=6

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(0, 0) &=& \frac{48r + 11}{(3r + 1)(144r^2 + 36r + 1)(144r^2 + 96r + 11)} \\
f(0, 1) = f(1, 0) &=& \frac{(6r + 1)(48r + 11)}{(3r + 1)(144r^2 + 36r + 1)(144r^2 + 96r + 11)} \\
f(0, 2) = f(2, 0) &=& \frac{1728r^3 + 1224r^2 + 234r + 11}{(3r + 1)(144r^2 + 36r + 1)(144r^2 + 96r + 11)} \\
f(1, 1) &=& \frac{1728r^3 + 1008r^2 + 192r + 11}{(3r + 1)(144r^2 + 36r + 1)(144r^2 + 96r + 11)} \\
f(0, 3) = f(3, 0) &=& \frac{10368r^4 + 10368r^3 + 3312r^2 + 384r + 11}{(3r + 1)(144r^2 + 36r + 1)(144r^2 + 96r + 11)} \\
f(1, 2) = f(2, 1) &=& \frac{10368r^4 + 9504r^3 + 2880r^2 + 336r + 11}{(3r + 1)(144r^2 + 36r + 1)(144r^2 + 96r + 11)} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

It looks reasonable to conjecture $f(0,1) = f(1,0) = (Nr+1)f(0, 0)$, but I'm not optimistic about getting anything further for the general case.

Comment: Yes, I agree it looks quite hopeless...

Comment: But thanks for giving it some thought anyway! :)